# In spring boot, GET request is returning 200 but POST request is returning 403

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, post, openapi

I've a spring boot application with **springdoc-openapi-ui** dependency, and without security.
The HTTP GET request is going through (status 200).  But the HTTP POST request is not going through (status 403).  What could be the reason for the 403 return code on the POST request?

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.chartinvest</groupId>
    <artifactId>ta</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <open-api>1.6.8</open-api>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.7</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${open-api}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

**Spring controller class**

```
@RestController
public class TaController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/ping", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String pingGet() {
        log.info("/ping");
        return "ok";
    }

    @Operation(summary = "test")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String test(String string) {
        log.info("/test");
        return "ok !!";
    }
```

**swagger**

[image]

Comment: What is `String string` supposed to be? Did you try removing it?

Comment: The POST is just receiving a String in the payload.  Why should I remove it ?

Answer (score 1):

[RequestParam](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html) annotation is missing. Please use below method. You need to invoke POST method with request param key `string`

And ResponseBody annotation is also missing.

```
@Operation(summary = "test")
        @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public @ResponseBody String test(@RequestParam("string") String string) {
            log.info("/test");
            return "ok !!";
        }
```

Comment: The RequestBody annotation didn't have any positive result.  It still returns 403

Comment: Check updated snippet with request param.

Comment: still returns 403

Comment: @user2023141 Ever heard of server error logs?

Comment: No log entries in the  application log file.  The  log.info("/test");  is not there

Comment: @user2023141 You should see a Spring exception in the Tomcat logs.

Comment: I'll have to ask the system person where tomcat is installed ....I'll know next monday

Answer (score 0):

Either you have to use `@RequestParam` within your `test` method or you have to remove `String string` argument :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String test(@RequestParam(name= "string")String string) {
        log.info("/test");
        return "ok !!";
    }
```

Comment: Above syntax is not correct. Intellij marks   @RequestAttribute  with red sayng  '=' expected

Comment: just updated code, this `value` name should be same as your input . I have given "string" here for demo purpose; if it didn't work, share your input payload

Comment: Sorry...I don't understand ....can you pass the correct code please ?

Comment: can you please share input payload? I mean how you are executing your `post` request

Comment: I execute the POST via swagger... I'll add a picture

Comment: well, I just rereferred your screen shot & changed my code. I have tested my code by using white space in my attribute & I am able to get response back. Can you recheck. In fact, your charset is also UTF-8 which is correct.

Comment: If I do the test locally on my PC, all works.  But when I copy the war into the server, and test it on the server, then I get the 403.

Answer (score 0):

this works:

```
        @Operation(summary = "test")
        @PostMapping("/test")
        public  String test(@RequestBody String string) {
            log.info("/test");
            return "ok !!";
        }
```

this will expect the string as a body.
please make sure you refresh the swagger interface after you apply the fix.

for header:

```
        @Operation(summary = "test")
        @PostMapping("/test")
        public  String test(@RequestHeader("someHeader") String string){
            log.info("/test");
            return "ok !!";
        }
```

for path variable:

```
        @Operation(summary = "test")
        @PostMapping("/test/{somePath}")
        public  String test(@PathVariable("somePath") String string){
            log.info("/test");
            return "ok !!";
        }
```